# Javascript- Sintaxe de classes

Tags: javascript, classes

```
class Greeter {
   constructor(message) {
   this.greeting = message;
   /* this.greet = () => {
    return "Hello, " + this.greeting; --> Método dentro do construtor  */ 
}

greet() {
return "Hello, " + this.greeting;
  }
};

var greeter = new Greeter("world");
console.log(greeter.greet());
```

Tem alguma diferença ou consequências de colocar os métodos dentro do construtor ou fora? Ou é mera convenção da galera?

Comment: Nunca vi colocarem os métodos dentro do construtor. Onde viu isso?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Criar métodos dentro do construtor quase nunca é uma boa opção. Uma grande utilidade desta notação é a facilidade da criação de variáveis privadas, visto que os métodos criados ali dentro terá seu escopo fechado ao método construtor. Veja um exemplo:

```js
class Greeter {
    constructor(message) {
        const greeting = message; // variavel privada
        
        this.greet = () => {
             return "Hello, " + greeting;
        }
    }
}

console.log(new Greeter("World").greet())
```

A desvantagem de usar desta forma é que, toda vez que você criar um objeto a partir da classe `Greeter`, o javascript irá criar todos os métodos novamente, causando um uso maior de memoria de forma desnecessária, sendo que, se você escrever os métodos de forma convencional dentro da classe, ele consegue otimizar isso para que não tenha várias funções em memória que fazem exatamente a mesma coisa.

A conclusão é que, se você tem poucas instâncias da classe `Greeter` e o seu código fica realmente melhor com variáveis privadas, use, caso contrário, não use. :)